# Structs within structs causing problems

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, struct

I'm designing a basic game engine for a class. There are 3 basic parts, GameObjects (which are objects in my game), Events (Event based engine), and Arguments (Can be things such as ints and floats that are passed inside Events). If I don't include "Event.h" (which includes GameObject.h and Argument.h), I get no errors, so it compiles cleanly. However, if I try to include the header file, it throws a fit. I can't see any problems no matter how hard I look, my header files do not have a circular dependency, and all of my structs are clearly defined. Header files shouldn't be re-defining each other. Not really sure what to do now. I'll add the files below.

**GameObject.h**

```
#ifndef GAMEOBJECT_H
#define GAMEOBJECT_H

typedef struct GameObject;
struct GameObject
{
  char *name;
};

#endif
```

**Argument.h**

```
#ifndef ARGUMENT_H
#define ARGUMENT_H

#include "GameObject.h"

enum ARG_TYPES
{
  TYPE_INT = 0,
  TYPE_FLOAT,
  TYPE_DOUBLE,
  TYPE_STRING,
  TYPE_CHAR,
  TYPE_GO,
  TYPE_NULL = -1
};

typedef struct Argument;
struct Argument
{
  char *name;
  int type;

  union
  {
    int         _int;
    float       _float;
    double      _double;
    char       *_string;
    char        _char;
    GameObject *_go;
  };
};
#endif
```

**Event.h**

```
#ifndef EVENT_H
#define EVENT_H

#include "GameObject.h"
#include "Argument.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

#define MAX_ARGS 8

enum EVENT_TYPE
{
  EVENT_INPUT = 1,
  EVENT_GAMEPLAY = 2,
  EVENT_COLLISION = 3,
  EVENT_OBJECT = 4,
  EVENT_NULL = -1
};

typedef struct Event;
struct Event
{
  int type;             //this is the type of event that this event is. 
  char *name;           //the name of the current event. If we include hashing, this will change to a number
  unsigned int arg_num; //the number of arguments currently held by the event. This is mostly for adding events
  Argument *args;       //An array of arguments. To understand an argument, look at Argument.h
  int flag;             //A flag as to whether this event is in use. Used for optimizing searching
};

//there are a bunch of functions here, but they just cause the errors. 
#endif
```

I get these errors repeated over and over. Other errors basically come from my structs not being defined, so the compiler yells about how their type doesn't exist.

```
//this one is repeated over and over a TON. 
error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'
error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
error C2059: syntax error : 'type'
error C2059: syntax error : ')'
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Professional, compiling in C (I set the compiler option manually).

Comment: You should treat names starting with `_` as reserved for the implementation.  It is possible that names such as `_int` are used by the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing something really weird with `typedef`.

What you've written here:

```
typedef struct Argument;
```

should be something like:

```
typedef struct Argument Argument;
```

`struct Argument` is the underlying type, and you want to `typedef` it as `Argument`.

Right now, you're basically trying to tell it to replace the word `struct` with the word `Argument` wherever it occurs, which can only lead to tears.

The usual usage would be something like:

```
typedef struct GameObject
{
  char *name;
} GameObject;
```

or:

```
struct GameObject
{
  char *name;
};
typedef struct GameObject GameObject;
```

Comment: I was trying to make sure that Argument was 100% defined before I used it in a struct. I tried doing as you suggested, no improvement. Previously, all my structs were defined as <br/>


`typedef struct
{
  
}Argument;`

Sorry about the formatting, I'm fighting this comment box.

Comment: It's almost definitely your issue. As an aside, using short and common names like `EVENT_H` and `ARGUMENT_H` as include guards is risky, as the shorter and more common you make it, the higher the likelihood that some other file you include will also define it. Things like `DAVES_NEW_GAME_ENGINE_EVENT_H` or something along those lines is safer.

Comment: What the other guy said above fixed it, using _int and _float causes a tidal flood of problems. Probably a dumb way to name things in retrospect, since _variable is reserved for Microsoft stuff.